# Nodejs SDK: adding s3 bucket eventnotification from aws cli got InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I did the below way to add event notification to s3 bucket using node js simple sdk
from ec2 instance.

```
var params={
        Bucket: name,
        NotificationConfiguration: {
          QueueConfigurations: [],
          TopicConfigurations: [],        
          LambdaFunctionConfigurations: [{
            "Id": "enableS3EventForTransformCurLambda",
            "LambdaFunctionArn": arn,
            "Events": [ "s3:ObjectCreated:*" ],
            "Filter": { "Key": { "FilterRules": [ { "Name": "Suffix", "Value": ".json" } ] } }
          }
          ]
        }
    }


const notifevent = await s3.putBucketNotificationConfiguration(paramsNotif).promise();
```

Now I am getting error

```
InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations
```

It construct correct params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by adding permission to the Lambda that  is triggered from s3 event.

by below way

```
async function addPermissionToLambda(){
    
    var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
    var paramsForNotification = {
       Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction", 
       FunctionName: "lambda-fn", 
       Principal: "s3.amazonaws.com", 
       SourceAccount: acctNum, 
       SourceArn: "arn:aws:s3:::*-test-bucket", 
       StatementId: "s3LambdaInvokeViaS3Event"
    };
    
    var paramsForGetPolicy = {
        FunctionName: "lambda-fn"
    };
    
    
    
        try{
        const permission = await lambda.addPermission(paramsForNotification).promise()
        console.log("Permission Added to the lambda for invoke it")
        
        
        }catch(err){
            console.log("Error occured while addding permissioon to lambda")
            console.log(err, err.stack)
        }
    
}
```

Now you can easily add event notification to the bucket.